# Filtering path with variable length multiple relationships (People You May Know query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

So let's say we have `User` nodes, `Company` nodes, `Project` nodes, `School` nodes and `Event` nodes. And there are the following relationships between these nodes

- `(User)-[:WORKED_AT {start: timestamp, end:timestamp}]->(Company)`
- `(User)-[:COLLABORATED_ON]->(Project)`
- `(Company)-[:COLLABORATED_ON]->(Project)`
- `(User)-[:IS_ATTENDING]->(Event)`
- `(User)-[:STUDIED_AT]->(School)`

I am trying to recommend users to any given user. My starting query looks like this

```
MATCH p=(u:User {id: {leftId}})-[r:COLLABORATED_ON|:AUTHORED|:WORKED_AT|:IS_ATTENDING|:STUDIED_AT*1..3]-(pymk:User)
RETURN p
LIMIT 24
```

Now this returns me all the `pymk` users within 1 to 3 relationships away, which is fine. But I want to filter the path according to the relationship attributes. Like remove the following path if the `user` and `pymk` work start date and end date is not overlapping.

`(User)-[:WORKED_AT]->(Company)<-[:WORKED_AT]-(User)`

I can do this with single query

```
MATCH (u:User)-[r1:WORKED_AT]->(Company)<-[r2:WORKED_AT]-(pymk:User)
WHERE 
    (r1.startedAt <  r2.endedAt) AND (r2.startedAt < r1.endedAt)
RETURN pymk
```

But couldn't get my head around doing it within a collection of paths. I don't even know if this is possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
MATCH p=(:User {id: {leftId}})-[:COLLABORATED_ON|:AUTHORED|:WORKED_AT|:IS_ATTENDING|:STUDIED_AT*1..3]-(:User)
WITH p, [rel in relationships(p) WHERE type(rel) = 'WORKED_AT'] as worked
WHERE size(worked) <> 2 OR 
  apoc.coll.max([work in worked | work.startedAt]) < apoc.coll.min([work in worked | work.endedAt])
RETURN p
LIMIT 24
```

We're using APOC here to get the max and min of a collection (the `max()` and `min()` aggregation functions in just Cypher are aggregation functions across rows, and can't be used on lists).

This relies on distilling the logic of overlapping down to `max([start times]) < min([end times])`, which you can check out in this [highly popular answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/92359)